# re-attach battery driven gamepad to PC power supply

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, battery-operated, computers

There are times at that I get mad about empty AA batteries or accumulators losing their capacity too early. And since the gaming computer is running anyway, I thought about using one of the molex connectors to run a wire out of the computer casing and use it as power source for the currently battery-driven gamepad.

The plan:
Molex connector gives 12V/5V, convert the 5V to 1.4V

My tests:

1. AA akku, Multimeter, Gamepad:  the gamepad drains roughly 60mA
2. power supply, Multimeter, electronic parts: 
   5V of power supply are converted to 3.3V by a MCP1702-3302;
   the remaining 1.9V shall be reduced by ~30 Ohm resistors in series.
   As the power supply is switching power to the 5V and the MCP1702 is also switching to 3.3V, I added a 10V/2200 microFarad capacitor at the end, before running power to the gamepad and connecting is to ground.

Result:
The gamepad's power Led is fading/blinking, the device is not working.

I understood that resistors reduce power and current, thus I took the current into account:
R= U/I = (3.3V-1.4V) / 0.06A = 31.67Ohm
Measuring the resulting voltage with the gamepad attached was driving my multimeter crazy.

Is my approach okay? 
Does the capacitor flatten the switched power enough to simulate a battery?

Comment: If you have regulator for 3.3 V, you don't need to worry about 1.9 V drop. For 60 mA of current, the regulator will be fine handling the load at the input voltage of 5 V. You may remove the resistor and try.

Comment: @umar op needs 1.1~1.6 at max. A 3.3V output is 200% of what is needed and likely will cause problems.

Comment: @Passerby I had read the question upside down :) Eventually left a wrong comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a simple resistor to drop your voltage because this is very dependent on current draw.  And your controller is drawing varying amounts of current, depending on which buttons are pressed, and LEDs, etc.

For example, the controller might be drawing 60 mA when idle, but much more when active.  If it draws more, this will cause the resistor to drop more voltage, and the circuit could starve.

What you want it to use a voltage regulator that outputs what you need.  To use the same family of parts that you are currently using, try a MCP1702-1502 instead of your MCP1702-3302.

If it turns out that the device uses more than 200 mA, perhaps if it vibrates (?), then even the MCP1702 won't be able to provide enough current.

Comment: Yes it only uses one AA battery. The model is "Saitek P2900 wireless"

Comment: @nicht-vergessen Thanks, I removed that question from my answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the hint on the MCP1702-1502. I wasn't considering that, because last time I checked my shops , these where hard to find as TO-package. Luckily, now they are available again.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it helps :)

Comment: I checked the device again, the load will vary to max 250mA. I have not seen that in testing, but I guess two MCP1702-1502 (200mA max each) in parallel shall provide enough current. the atx power supply behind give enough.

Comment: @nicht-vergessen I agree that the ATX supply should be sufficient. But I question using parallel regulators.  At the very least, you should put a small series resistance between each regulator and the device. It will drop your voltage slightly, and waste a bit of power, but it will help balance the two regulators.  Instead, I recommend finding a beefier regulator, such as the [LMS1587IT-1.5](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lms1585a.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a molex connection, a usb cord is sufficient for the same 5V supply, with a smaller connector. You can still use the 3.3V regulator. Instead of resistors,  a few diodes are better. 3 2n4001 diodes in series should produce a 2.1 Volt drop, so you have 1.2V output. The controller should run off this fine if it works on a NiMH rechargeable.

The other option is no regulator and 5 Diodes in series. 3.5V drop. So 5V - 3.5V = 1.5V of a single AA.

Comment: Good point on the usb connection. But the 12V of the molex is already in use for an external bluray drive, to get rid of the additional power plug. ;-) So practically the molex is outside already.